# Elasticsearch: Getting analyzer used for indexing a given field from the client side

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene, client, analyzer

Is there a way to programmatically getting the [analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/analysis-analyzers.html) used for indexing a given field by the Elasticsearch server instance via a client (assuming that the analyzer is available on both sides, of course)?

For example, using a mapping such as:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "article": {
            "properties": {
                "text": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "analyzed",
                    "analyzer": "spanish"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

how would it be possible to get [`org.apache.lucene.analysis.es.SpanishAnalyzer`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/es/SpanishAnalyzer.html) for the field `text` using [the Java client for Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/client.html), as shown below?

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Collections;

import org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequestBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.InetSocketTransportAddress;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders;
import org.elasticsearch.search.SearchHit;

public class QueryAnalyzerTest {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
        final String docTextFieldName = "text";
        Iterable<SearchHit> hits = Collections.emptyList();

        try (final Client client = TransportClient.builder().build()
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300))) {
            final QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.matchQuery(docTextFieldName, "anuncio");
            final SearchRequestBuilder searchRequestBuilder = client.prepareSearch("news").setQuery(queryBuilder)
                    .setTypes("article");
            final SearchResponse response = searchRequestBuilder.get();
            hits = response.getHits();
        }

        hits.forEach(hit -> {
            final String docText = (String) hit.getSource().get(docTextFieldName);
            // TODO: Tokenize "docText" with the exact same tokenizer used when
            // indexing the field
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely get the mapping of the `text` field programmatically using `client().admin().indices().prepareGetFieldMappings("indexName")`, and you'll be able to retrieve the logical name of the analyzer (i.e. "spanish"), however, you won't get the class name of the analyzer.

For that you need to call [`AnalysisRegistry.getAnalyzer("spanish")`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/d12a4bb51dbeee9e0210b1977495221aa0348cb1/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/analysis/AnalysisRegistry.java#L116), and you'll get the proper analyzer instance.

Comment: The first part was spot-on, but unfortunately I don't have an `AnalysisRegistry` class (I'm running Elasticsearch 2.3.2); Has the API changed?

Comment: No, but probably that `AnalysisRegistry` is not being included in the client JAR, that wouldn't surprise me.

Comment: Not much: I found that there are an `org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.AnalysisService` and `org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.AnalysisModule` which are available client-side, but the relevant instance(s) seem to be injected by an embedded Guice framework; I'm still not sure how to get these injected instances-- or even if they're there at all on the client side.

Comment: With `AnalysisService.analyzer("spanish")` you don't get anything?

Comment: The main question is how I get an instance of `AnalysisService` so that I can call that method...